# Use more inputs one post request - and have controller recognize which input was clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to have 2 input buttons on a page for one form. Each of these buttons should trigger the same controller POST action (so update the model in the same manner, basically update cart quantities). Now, in the controller - with the same action I would like to additionally trigger 2 alternative behaviours. Option 1 - redirect to page x (keep shopping), 2 - send email, finalize transaction, redirect to y page.

I don't know where to start with guiding controller to understand which button was clicked ? Likely these inputs should have an id or name and the model would be able to recognize them this way, but I'm not sure how to guide the controller to do so?

I would preferably look for solution without jquery javascript etc. Will greatly appreciate help.

**View**

```
@model Project.ViewModels.CartViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
for (int i =0; i < Model.CartItems.Count; i++ )
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.CartItems[i].Product.Name)
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Quantity)
}
<input type="submit" name="emailName" id="emailId" value="Send E-mail" />
<input type="submit" name="emailName" id="emailId" value="Redirect" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Show(CartViewModel cvm)
{
if (TryUpdateModel(cvm))
{
    if( ??? )return RedirectToAction("x", "Home");
    if( ??? )
      { 
       //send E-mail
       return RedirectToAction("y", "Home");
      }
}
```

Comment: Add a parameter `string emailName` to the POST method. The value will either "Send E-mail" or "Redirect" depending on which button you clicked. And remove the `id` attributes from your buttons - is invalid html to have duplicate `id` attributes

Comment: Many thanks for help again :) removing ids is clear, and perhaps adding a parameter would help as well but how do I then refer to this parameter in if statement (I would probably need something in the direction of if(... .value = "Send E-mail") ) ?

Comment: It's sorted below, thanks for the hints anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're after something like this...

**View**

```
@model Project.ViewModels.CartViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.CartItems.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Product.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Quantity)
    }
    <button name="action" type="submit" value="email">Send E-mail</button>
    <button name="action" type="submit" value="redirect">Redirect</button>

}
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Show(CartViewModel cvm, string action)
{
    if(action == "email")
    {
        //Do something
    }

    if(action == "redirect")
    {
        //Do something
    }

}
```